# How can I make Ajax Script for form submission work on multiple forms

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a working Ajax script that submits a form and display content in a DIV on success, but at the moment it only work when I have 1 form, but on my page I need to have multiple forms that should use this script for form submission and response back to the user.

The Ajax:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
      $("form").validate();
    });
    $( "form" ).on( "submit", function(e) {

        var dataString = $(this).serialize();

        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "update_userdata.asp",
          data: dataString,
          success: function () {
            $("#EconomyColumnsResponse2").html("<div id='message' style='background-color: #28a745;'></div>");
            $("#message")
              .html("<font style='color: white;'>Løn Information er nu opdateret <i class='fas fa-check-circle'></i></font>")
              .hide()
              .fadeIn(1500, function () {
                $("#message").append(
                  ""
                );
              });
          }
        });

        e.preventDefault();
      });
      setTimeout(function(){
        $('#EconomyColumnsResponse2').fadeOut('slow');
      }, 15000)

</script>
```

Lets say I have 2 forms (there will be many more also with same name but different attached ID i.e EconomyColumns1 = Name + ID) that looks like this:

```
<div id="EconomyColumnsResponse1">
</div>
<form name="EconomyColumns1" id="EconomyColumns1" action="">
<input type="hidden" name="UserID" id="UserID" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="ColumnToUpdate" id="ColumnToUpdate" value="EconomyColumns">
  <fieldset>
    <div class="input-box">
      <label for="name" id="name_label">lonnr</label>
      <input type="text" name="lonnr" id="lonnr" minlength="3" class="text-input" required/>
    </div>
    <div class="input-box">
      <label for="email" id="email_label">debnr</label>
      <input type="text" name="debnr" id="debnr" class="text-input"/>
    </div>
    <div class="input-box">
      <label for="phone" id="phone_label">orgnr</label>
      <input type="text" name="orgnr" id="orgnr" class="text-input"/>
    </div>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit_btn" value="Send" />
  </fieldset>
</form>

<div id="EconomyColumnsResponse2">
</div>
<form name="EconomyColumns2" id="EconomyColumns1" action="">
<input type="hidden" name="UserID" id="UserID" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="ColumnToUpdate" id="ColumnToUpdate" value="EconomyColumns">
  <fieldset>
    <div class="input-box">
      <label for="name" id="name_label">lonnr</label>
      <input type="text" name="lonnr" id="lonnr" minlength="3" class="text-input" required/>
    </div>
    <div class="input-box">
      <label for="email" id="email_label">debnr</label>
      <input type="text" name="debnr" id="debnr" class="text-input"/>
    </div>
    <div class="input-box">
      <label for="phone" id="phone_label">orgnr</label>
      <input type="text" name="orgnr" id="orgnr" class="text-input"/>
    </div>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit_btn" value="Send" />
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

How can I make my Ajax become dynamically so that I do not need to have as many Ajax scripts as I have forms, but only need to have on? .. as a little twist, the  $("#message").. should be different depending on the form that is submitted.

Hope somone can help :-)

Best Regards

Stig :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Barmar .. Here is the updated HTML form

```
<div id="response_div">
</div>
<form name="Initials2"  id="Initials2" action="">
<input type="hidden" name="UserID" id="UserID" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="ColumnToUpdate" id="ColumnToUpdate" value="InitialsColumn">
  <fieldset>
    <div class="input-box">
    <label for="Initials" id="Initials">Initials</label>
    <input type="text" name="Initials" id="Initials" minlength="3" maxlength="3" class="text-input" required/>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" form="Initials2" value="Submit">Send</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>


<div id="response_div">
</div>
<form name="EconomyColumns1" id="EconomyColumns1" action="">
<input type="hidden" name="UserID" id="UserID" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="ColumnToUpdate" id="ColumnToUpdate" value="EconomyColumns">
<fieldset>
<div class="input-box">
  <label for="lonnr" id="lonnr_label">lonnr</label>
  <input type="text" name="lonnr" id="lonnr" minlength="3" class="text-input" required/>
</div>
<div class="input-box">
  <label for="debnr" id="debnr_label">debnr</label>
  <input type="text" name="debnr" id="debnr" class="text-input"/>
</div>
<div class="input-box">
  <label for="orgnr" id="orgnr_label">orgnr</label>
  <input type="text" name="orgnr" id="orgnr" class="text-input"/>
</div>
  <button type="submit" form="EconomyColumns1" value="Submit">Send</button>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Don't use an answer for more questions. Add it to the question (without removing the original code).

Answer (score 0):

Set a variable to the DIV before the form, and use that in the callback function.

```
$("form").on("submit", function(e) {

  var dataString = $(this).serialize();
  let response_div = $(this).prev();

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "update_userdata.asp",
    data: dataString,
    success: function() {
      response_div.html("<div id='message' style='background-color: #28a745;'></div>");
      $("#message")
        .html("<font style='color: white;'>Løn Information er nu opdateret <i class='fas fa-check-circle'></i></font>")
        .hide()
        .fadeIn(1500, function() {
          $("#message").append(
            ""
          );
        });
    }
  });

  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Hi Barmar .. I have just updated my code, with your script and new Form code.. I see your code is giving some of the result I need, but still there is some issues .. 1. The message $("#message") how can I send this dynamic from the form to the script?  .. 2 Even though my button target form="EconomyColumns1" it validates input on form "Initials2". .. 3. The response_div display the correct div on first submit og EconomyColumns1, but if I submit a second time it targets the DIV in Initials2. .. 4. How do I handle the setTimeout(function() dynamically.

Comment: Don't replace the code in the question with the answer, how will anyone understand what problem I was fixing? I put back the original code.

Comment: Sorry Barmar, you are correct .. that was a misstake I will not make again... the updated Form Code I think though will make it more understandable.

Comment: 1. I don't understand what you want to do dynamically with `#message`.

Comment: Element IDs are required to be unique. You can't use the same `id="lonnr"` in both forms. That may be the problem with the validation.

Comment: Use classes instead of IDs, then you can use `$(this).find(".lonnr")` in your validation code.

Comment: I'm not sure what the purpose of the `setTimeout()` is. It's not part of the form submission code.

Comment: 1 : I need to change the message that it returns in the response_div.html("<div id='message' ... depending on the form that submits.
2 : I have just made some changes to the HTML Form, that I will post, it is still giving me the same result that it validates a different form and shows the incorrect DIV..
3. The SetTimeout is to have the DIV disapear again

Comment: Put the `setTimeout` in the `success` function, then it can use `response_div.fadeOut('slow')`

Comment: If you need the message to depend on the form, you should add an attribute to the form that the common code can check and use in the message. Use `data-XXX` attributes for custom data.

Comment: Are you use jquery-validate for the validation? How have you configured the rules?

Comment: Brilliant, the SetTimeout in the success works like a charm.  You where correct regarding the validate, when I removed that it did not require the field in the other form - I will be using another validation and not jQuery, so that is fine.

Comment: However,.. Can you give me an example on how to use data-XXX attributes for custom data? .. and there is still an issue that I cannot resubmit the form again after first submit, that said it does submit the data, but the div is not being shown.,

Comment: Something like `<form data-message="This is something that should be displayed in #message">`. Then you can use `let message = $(this).data("message");`

Comment: Where exactly should I put let message = $(this).data("message");?  .. I have just tried like this .html(let message = $(this).data("message");)  .. and also replaced entire line of .html("<font style='color:.... with let message = $(this).data("message"); but does not work

Comment: The same place you put `let response_div`.

Comment: ```$("#message").html(`<font style='color: white;'>${message} <i class='fas fa-check-circle'></i></font>`)```

Comment: I just noticed another problem: You're adding `id="message"` in both response DIVs. You can't use the same ID in both places. Use a class instead of ID. Then you can use `response_div.find(".message").html(...)`

Comment: I'm not going to write this whole thing for you. I thought you would understand the general idea and be able to run with it.

Comment: Thank you, the Message works brilliant now.  .. I am sorry to take up your time, I am a novice in with AJAX. I have tried to change id="response_div" to class="response_div" but I cannot get that to work .. Do you think that the issue on not being able to display message on second submit has something to do with that?